# React JS calling delete API with request body

Tags: reactjs, rest

My **Delete API** is `http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/deleteproduct` with the request body in JSON format:

```
{
    "upc": "100101101111"
}
```

**upc** is the unique value for each product.

Here is my code for fetching data from API:

```
export function Inventory() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/products")
      .then((response) => {
        setProduct(response.data);
      });
  }, [url]);

  if (product) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Brand</th>
              <th scope="col">Category</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
              <th scope="col">Price Per Unit</th>
              <th scope="col">Available Stock</th>
              <th scope="col">Reserved Stock</th>
              <th scope="col">Shipped Stock</th>
              <th scope="col">Image</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {product.map((item) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.productName}</td>
                <td>{item.brand}</td>
                <td>{item.category}</td>
                <td>{item.productDescription}</td>
                <td>{item.pricePerUnit}</td>
                <td>{item.availableStock}</td>
                <td>{item.reservedStock}</td>
                <td>{item.shippedStock}</td>
                <td>
                  <img src={item.imageUrl} height={100} width={100} />
                </td>
          <td>
            <Button>
              onClick={() => {
              onDeleteProduct();
            }}
            style={{ color: "red", marginLeft: 12 }}
            /Button>
          </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've already done the part of GET method to fetch all the data from API to the table.

Now I'm working on the DELETE method. I've also already created a delete button in each row. But I have no idea how to get the `upc` value in the row that I click the delete button to call an API `http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/deleteproduct`.

Can someone give me some idea, please?

Comment: Does each item in the `products` array contain a `upc` id?

Comment: yes it is but I don't want to show it on UI page. It's available on the Databse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each item has a unique `upc`, then your function should accept this as an argument

```
      <td>
        <Button>
          onClick={() => {
          onDeleteProduct(item.upc);
        }}
        style={{ color: "red", marginLeft: 12 }}
        /Button>
      </td>
```

and then your method would become like this

```
onDeleteProduct = itemUpc => {
  axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/deleteproduct', { data: { upc: itemUpc }, headers: { } });
}
```